# Function Animation in multithreading not working

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, animation

I am using threads to generate a random number. Furthermore animation function is used for the plotting of a sine function. The purpose of the code is to run all the five functions concrentely.

```
import logging
import threading
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(threadName)-17s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=LOG_FORMAT)

items = []
event = threading.Event()


class Consumer(threading.Thread):# first random number class
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x=random.random()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(2)
            event.wait()
            print('first thread')
            


class Producer(threading.Thread): # second random number class
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.y=random.random()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            
            time.sleep(2)
            print('second thread')
            
            
            event.wait()
    
        
class anim(threading.Thread):# Animation function class
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)

            #self.init_sec()
            self.animate(200)
            self.animate_1()
            event.wait()

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
    def init_sec(self):
        self.line.set_data([], [])
        return self.line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
    def animate(self,i):
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
        self.y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (self.x - 0.01 * i))
        self.line.set_data(self.x,self.y)
        return self.line,
    def animate_1(self):

        
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func=self.init_sec) #this function doesnot work properly 
        print('third thread')
        
            
            
class CSV_file(Consumer,Producer,threading.Thread): Further the data is stored in the csv file. This #is future work
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        while True:

            time.sleep(2)
            print('fourth thread')
            event.set()
            print(self.x)
            print(self.y)
            event.clear()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Consumer()
    t2 = Producer()
    t3 = anim()
    t4 = CSV_file()
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
```

Comment: If you'd like for all of them to run simultaneously, maybe do not join the threads, just joining your main thread will be sufficient.
So, you should be able to join just t4 and that should be fine.
I Believe what might be happening is that the other threads are joining before the even can be set and waiting in the main thread.